# I'm calculating standard deviation with numbers with uncertainties, how do I do this?

Tags: standard-deviation

Just curious on how to calculate Standard Deviation of a Sample using non-pure numbers (numbers with uncertainties). I need some guidelines and such...

Thank you.

Comment: Try following the `error-propagation` tag on this site, or doing web searches with that phrase. If you have more specific questions with respect to your immediate interests, edit this question with more details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Interesting question. You will get much more useful answers if you provide an example of how you want to use this (e.g. provide a subset of your data, anonymised if necessary). Also, welcome to the site :)

Comment: It depends what it is you want the standard deviation *of*; there's a level of ambiguity that could best be resolved by putting it in the form of a model for the process you're describing and then explaining which variable you want the s.d. of.